# WCF REST Post Complex Object

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf

For some reason my AttributeContract object isn't being passed from my client to my service method correctly. I can successfully access the method via the call, but the object is empty. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here?

**Client**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string serviceCall = string.Format("{0}AttributeService.svc/AttributeDefinition/", _serviceLocation);

    int attributeIdInt = Convert.ToInt32(attributeId);
    int objectIdInt = Convert.ToInt32(objectId);

    AttributeContract attributeContract = new AttributeContract()
    {
        AttributeId = attributeIdInt,
        AttributeValue = attributeValue,
        ObjectId = objectIdInt,
        ObjectType = objectType
    };

    string attributeString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attributeContract);
    string requestJsonString = "{ \"attribute\" : " + attributeString + " }";

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, serviceCall);
    request.Content = new StringContent(requestJsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

}
```

**Data Contract**

```
[DataContract(Name = "AttributeContract")]
public class AttributeContract
{
    [DataMember(Name = "AttributeId")]
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Attribute")]
    public string Attribute { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AttributeValue")]
    public string AttributeValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ObjectId")]
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ObjectType")]
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "LastModifiedDate")]
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "LastModifiedUser")]
    public string LastModifiedUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Service Contract**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    UriTemplate = "AttributeDefinition/")]
void UpdateAttributes(AttributeContract attribute);
```

**Service Method**

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public void UpdateAttributes(AttributeContract attribute)
{
    attribute.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method not match: on service contract it is typed as PUT but on client it is POST. Also your object name not matched: attribute =! AttributeContract

Comment: Yes - the method was a mistake, which has since been corrected and with the same result.

Which object names need to the be same. The object name within the JSON and the Service Contract, Service Method... ? 

I've tried several different naming conventions as this seems to be the most obvious issue.

Comment: It is not important, don't use object name or method variable name. Send properties only: { AttributeId: 1, Attribute: "ss"}

Comment: Firstly make your service test with tools rather then c# code. For example chrome browser has an extension which name is Postman is best.

Comment: Okay - I've tried to send the JSON without the "attribute" wrapper, but it returns a 400 - bad request. I will look into Chrome, however, I'm using MVC and within the view I'm making an jQuery AJAX call to controller which turns around and calls the service via the methods above. So, when using the browser tools, I often only get the first jQuery AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

```
string serviceCall = string.Format("{0}AttributeService.svc/AttributeDefinition/", _serviceLocation);

    int attributeIdInt = Convert.ToInt32(attributeId);
    int objectIdInt = Convert.ToInt32(objectId);

    AttributeContract attributeContract = new AttributeContract()
    {
        AttributeId = attributeIdInt,
        AttributeValue = attributeValue,
        ObjectId = objectIdInt,
        ObjectType = objectType
    };

                    var request =
                        (HttpWebRequest)
                            WebRequest.Create(new Uri(serviceCall );
                    request.ContentType = "application/json";
                    request.Method = "PUT";
                    var itemToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                        attributeContract 
                        );
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(itemToSend);
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        streamWriter.Dispose();
                    }
```

Try this code

Comment: I was hoping to do everything using HttpClient. However, I am reviewing this and will potentially switch to WebRequest/WebResponse.

Comment: I remember I had problem also with httpclient and I used this way

Comment: When you did this, you were able to deserialize the JSON into the object on the service side and access its members?

Comment: If we send the JSON without the "attribute" wrapper we get a WebResponse of 400 - bad request. If we send with wrapper the object still never makes it to the service, however, we're able to get to the service with 200.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you don't need the object wrapper in the JSON (per mkysoft). A little digging in [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) revealed that I was having issues deserializing the datetime property on my Data Contract. I changed the property from DateTime to string while I determine the best path forward.